# Maven tomcat-maven-plugin set multiple levels context path

Tags: maven, tomcat

I am not sure if this is possible or I am doing somthing wrong.

I have myWebApp project. There is

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
                        <path>/myweb/test</path>
        </configuration>
```

in pom.xml

and controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    //controller
    }
```

I expect the home page URL would be `http://localhost:8080/myweb/test`, but it gives my 404 error.

So, can I set  to multiple levels, or am i missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: did u solve it? I have the same problem